# SpTBX: how to draw dock BG on canvas

Tags: delphi, sptbxlib

In TBX I had a code which draws Themed Dock BG on canvas.

```
var
  t: TTbxTheme;
  s:string;
  r: TRect;
..
  S:= TbxSwitcher.Theme;
  t:= GetTbxTheme(S);
  t.PaintDock(ACanvas.Handle, R, R, 0);
  ReleaseTBXTheme(t);
```

How to do it in SpTBX?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CurrentSkin (of sptbx) variable.

```
  CurrentSkin.PaintBackground(
    ACanvas, R,
    skncDock, sknsNormal, true{BG}, false{Borders});
```